# How to connect entries in a FHIR bundle resource belonging to the same time?

Tags: hl7-fhir

For example for an 'Observation' resource I want to have a bundle for 'blood pressure' observation, which will include 'systolic' and 'diastolic'. In the bundle I have observations for multiple dates. How can I connect  'systolic' and 'diastolic' observations belonging to the same date?

```js
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "title": "Multiple observations",
  "link": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "href": "http://localhost:3000/api/users/1/observations/bloodPressure?access_token=7ef61a51358a60fe875ca4a9ab3114c06d5818c25936f51bd420a5d1e025f0ee&end=2015-04-06T23:59&nocache=1441806074364&resolution=86400&start=2015-04-05T00:00&fhir=true"
    }
  ],
  "updated": "2015-09-09T15:14:10+00:00",
  "entry": [
    {
      "subject": {
        "reference": "/api/users/1"
      },
      "resourceType": "Observation",
      "name": {
        "coding": {
          "system": "http://loinc.org",
          "code": "8480-6",
          "display": "BP sys"
        }
      },
      "valueQuantity": {
        "value": 125,
        "units": "mm Hg",
        "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
        "code": "mm[Hg]"
      },
      "status": "final",
      "reliability": "ok",
      "appliesDateTime": "2015-04-05T14:44:00+00:00"
    },
    {
      "subject": {
        "reference": "/api/users/1"
      },
      "resourceType": "Observation",
      "name": {
        "coding": {
          "system": "http://loinc.org",
          "code": "8480-6",
          "display": "BP sys"
        }
      },
      "valueQuantity": {
        "value": 125,
        "units": "mm Hg",
        "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
        "code": "mm[Hg]"
      },
      "status": "final",
      "reliability": "ok",
      "appliesDateTime": "2015-04-06T09:25:00+00:00"
    },
    {
      "subject": {
        "reference": "/api/users/1"
      },
      "resourceType": "Observation",
      "name": {
        "coding": {
          "system": "http://loinc.org",
          "code": "8462-4",
          "display": "BP dias"
        }
      },
      "valueQuantity": {
        "value": 78,
        "units": "mm Hg",
        "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
        "code": "mm[Hg]"
      },
      "status": "final",
      "reliability": "ok",
      "appliesDateTime": "2015-04-05T14:44:00+00:00"
    },
    {
      "subject": {
        "reference": "/api/users/1"
      },
      "resourceType": "Observation",
      "name": {
        "coding": {
          "system": "http://loinc.org",
          "code": "8462-4",
          "display": "BP dias"
        }
      },
      "valueQuantity": {
        "value": 78,
        "units": "mm Hg",
        "system": "http://unitsofmeasure.org",
        "code": "mm[Hg]"
      },
      "status": "final",
      "reliability": "ok",
      "appliesDateTime": "2015-04-06T09:25:00+00:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've seen [this example](http://www.hl7.org/fhir/observation-example-bloodpressure.json.html), but it's not very clear to me still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DSTU 2, we've brought back Observation.component so systolic and diastolic should actually be captured as components of an overall blood pressure observation.  If you're using one of the intermediate versions, you'd still want to have an Observation that represented the overall blood pressure and then relationships from that observation the systolic and diastolic.  That would establish the linkage.

Comment: So, in DSTU2, should the Blood pressure data be inside a single Observation?

Comment: That's the recommendation, yes.

Comment: Thanks. I now found the Sept2015-version with that example. http://hl7.org/fhir/2015Sep/observation-example-bloodpressure.json ... So a measurement from the same equipment at the same time would be done like this? Also for example pulse oximeter with pulse and SpO2 I guess? Or if you had body-composition and weight...

Comment: I think there's more guidance required.  I would generally say that it's used for measurements that aren't useful alone - so systolic + diastolic or the parts of an APGAR.  But pulse and SpO2 would be useful alone - it's reasonable to want to query one and not the other, so those should be distinct observations.  If you'd like to raise a change request (Propose a Change link) to add some clarity, that wouldn't be a bad thing.